# AWS Athena. Can't use CSV manifest as a location

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, manifest, amazon-athena

I'm trying to create an external table in Athena, the problem is that the s3 bucket has different files in the same folder so I can't use the folder as a location.

I can't modify the path of the s3 files but I have a CSV manifest, I was trying to use it as a location but Athena didn't allow me to do that.

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_DB`.`my_external_table`(
    column1 string,
    column2 string
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar' = '\"',
   'escapeChar' = '\\'
   )
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://mys3bucket/tables/my_table.csvmanifest'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false', 
  'skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

Any ideas to use my manifest? or another way to solve this without Athena? The goal of using Athena was to avoid getting all the data from the CSVs since I only need few records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make a couple changes to your `CREATE TABLE` statement:

1. use `'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat'` as your `INPUTFORMAT`
2. Ensure you're pointing to a folder with your `LOCATION` statement

So your statement would look like:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_DB`.`my_external_table`(
    column1 string,
    column2 string
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar' = '\"',
   'escapeChar' = '\\'
   )
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://mys3bucket/tables/my_table/'
```

And `s3://mys3bucket/tables/my_table/` would have a single file in it with the S3 paths of the CSV files you want query - one path per line. I'm unsure if the `skip.header.line.count` setting will operate on the manifest file itself or the CSV files so you will have to test.

Alternatively, if you have a limited number of files, you could use [S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/selecting-content-from-objects.html) to query for specific columns in those files, one at a time. Using the AWS CLI, the command to extract the 2nd column would look something like:

```sh
aws s3api select-object-content \
  --bucket mys3bucket \
  --key path/to/your.csv.gz \
  --expression "select _2 from s3object limit 100" \
  --expression-type SQL \
  --input-serialization '{"CSV": {}, "CompressionType": "GZIP"}' \
  --output-serialization '{"CSV":{}}' \
  sample.csv
```

*(Disclaimer: AWS employee)*