# buffer s3 object inputs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

Does anyone know other than kinesis firehose, is there any other service from AWS can catch the S3 inject event? I am trying to do some analysis on VPC flow logs, currently setup is cloud-watch-logs -> Kinesis Firehose -> S3 -> Athena.

The problem is kinesis firehose can only buffer up to 128MB which is to small for me.

Answer (score 0):

Events from Amazon S3 can go to:

- AWS Lambda functions
- Amazon SNS topic
- Amazon SQS queue

So, you could **send the messages to an SQS queue and then have a regular process** (every hour?) that retrieves many messages and writes them to a single file.

Alternatively, you could use your current setup but **use Amazon Athena on a regular basis to *join* multiple files** by using `CREATE TABLE AS`. This would select from the existing files and store the output in a new table (with a new location). You could even use it to transform the files into a format that is easier to query in Athena (eg Snappy-compressed Parquet). The hard part is to only include each input file once into this concatenation process (possibly using [SymlinkTextInputFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55590099/174777)).

Comment: thank you John. I am trying to avoid lambda in this case as hourly there are over 100,000 file created from cloud-watch logs, handling lambda retries, DLQ with that many invocations could be a pain. I think the Athena way might be the best even though there are some trickiness. If that works I can remove kinesis from the diagram which is quite expensive. I'll give it a try, thank you